# Как правильно добавить на все страницы сайта форму?

Tags: django

Я создал в папке проекта файл forms.py

```
from django import forms
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
your_name = forms.CharField(label="Your name", max_length=100, required=False)
```

В общем шаблоне прописал так:

```
...html...
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
...html...
```

в компонентах пишу

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['main_form'] = ContactForm
    return context
```

форма выводится на страницах, но при попытке ее отправить, получаю 405 ошибку. Как правильно обработать форму в таком случае? нужна перезагрузка страницы и сообщение рядом с формой или вместо нее, что данные отправлены.

Comment: Ну как минимум указать правильный action